# jQuery - text field value change after jquery auto complete select event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple text field change after jquery auto complete select event. I want to split the data and display it in other text fields. I am trying this. This doesn't change any values at all. What do I need to change here?

```
$(function() {
  $("#term").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
      $.post("/users/search", request, response);
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui){
        $('#div2').html(ui.item.value); #doesn't populate with new text. 
        document.getElementById('#found').value="test"; #for test
        } #doesn't populate with new text. 
          #I want selected data to go here in the 'found' element id
  });
});
```

Ruby/html -

```
<%= text_field_tag :found, nil, :maxlength => 11, :size => 20%>
<input id="found" maxlength="11" name="found" size="20" type="text" />
```

Comment: What type of element is `#found`?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - Text field. `<%= text_field_tag :found, nil, :maxlength => 11, :size => 20%>`

Comment: Does the `select` event fire at all? What happens when you place an `alert` in the handler?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker - yes - it does. If I change it to html `<a id="found"></a>` then it gets populated at nicely.

Comment: It populates to a and p tags. but not to input tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
document.getElementById('#found').value="test"; #for test
```

to:

```
$('#found').val('test');
```

Comment: That worked. I want to split it before populating. How to split the data?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'split'?